# jQuery get number of values

Tags: jquery

So, I have the following js:

```
var my_content = data.number;
alert(my_content);
```

Which I get the following alert: "1,2,3,4,5,6"

So, there are 6 values in this variable.

**Problem**

I want to get the number of values for `for` function:

```
var my_content = data.number;
    alert(my_content);
var length = data.number.length;
    alert(length);
```

For the `my_content`, I get `1,2,3,4,5,6` (Good).

For the `length`, I get `11` (bad). So it looks like it is counting every single characters.

How do I get the number of values?

**EDIT**

Just realized that there is a comma at the end of the value `""1,2,3,4,5,6,"`

Comment: `data.number.length`? what about `data.content.length`?

Comment: Opps, fixed the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the `replace()` function with a little regex:

```
var my_content = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
var getLength = my_content.trim().replace(/,/g, "").length;
console.log(getLength);//prints 6
```

To meet the new requirement of your string ending with `,`, you can use `trim()` to eliminate any whitespace. The regex will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like its a string and you can use `data.content.split(',')` to get an array, but it will be an array of strings.

Comment: `data.content.split(',').length` should give you the amount

Comment: Just a quick question. So, I made a mistake and I am getting `1,2,3,4,5,6,` as the value. There is a `' , '` at the end and it gives me one more value. Is there a way to remove last "null" value?

Comment: @steveKim there are plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: I guess I can simply add "- 1".

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[^,]/g` to match characters that are not `,`

```
var n = "1,2,3,4,5,6".match(/[^,]/g);
console.log(n.length);
```